# Typescript error : Property defined as private on type Class is defined as public on type Interface

Tags: typescript

I just started a new project in TypeScript 0.9.5 and the following code is throwing an error :

**Class Service declared IService but does not implement it. Property 'getUserInfo' defined as private on type Service is defined as public on type IService**

```
 module App.Interfaces {

     export interface IService {
        getUserInfo(): void;

    }   
}

module App.Services {

    export class Service implements App.Interfaces.IService {

        private getUserInfo(): void { }

    }   
}
```

For as long as I've used TypeScript I know that interfaces cannot have access modifiers! What gives?

[Typescript playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20App.Interfaces%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20IService%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09getUserInfo%28%29%3a%20void;%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Amodule%20App.Services%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09export%20class%20Service%20implements%20App.Interfaces.IService%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09private%20getUserInfo%28%29%3a%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have the `private` access modifier on the `getUserInfo` function on the `Service` class as it's declared on the interface `IService`.

If the class is a `IService`, it needs to have **all** of the functions/properties of the interface declared publicly.

```
module App.Services {

    export class Service implements App.Interfaces.IService {

        /* private <= remove */ getUserInfo(): void { }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Making is public is the obvious solution. Sorry I didnt clarify that I was just not understanding why it's like this. However, after verifying the same behavior in C#, I realize it's just one of those details I never ran into before and found odd.